# JQuery .show() is not working for textarea

Tags: jquery

I have below code -

```js
$( document ).ready($(function() {
 $("#app_type").on("change",function() {
    var selectedTestType = $(this).find("option").filter(":selected").text();
    $(".hideable").hide();
    if(selectedTestType=="App-1")
    {
   $("#show_element").show();
 }).change();
}));
```

```css
#show_element {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Form Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="form_verify.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
        <label>Form Element</label></br>
                                <select id="app_type" class="form-control" name="form_element">
         <option selected disabled>-- Select Application Type --</option>
         <option>App-1</option>
         <option>App-2</option>
        </select>
                            </div>
<div class="form-group hideable" id="show_element">
        <label>Steps</label></br>
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Steps" name="form_steps" type="text" value="" rows="2"></textarea>
                            </div>
```

The textarea is hidden initially but should show up when App-1 is selected in dropdown. With the provided code, textarea is hiding but not showing up when App-1 is selected. Please advice what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Where is `#app_type`?

Comment: It's a good idea when posting a stack snippet to try and remove all errors before posting. Like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Comment: `$(this).find("option").filter(":selected").text();` -> `$(this).val()` why overcomplicate.

Comment: FWIW that's kind of a convoluted way to get the selected option.  can simplify selectedTestType to `$("#app_type option:selected").text();` -- or even just `$(this).val()` in this case (since there's no value attribute on the options.)

Comment: `id="id="app_type"` you need to fix all the typos

Comment: @KevinB In that code, `this` refers to the **div** with `id="app_type"` (rightly or wrongly), so `$(this).val()` would not work.

Comment: @ tymeJV HTML has #app_type now, @ freedomn-m typo is fixed

Comment: @freedomn-m at the time KevinB posted that comment , there was no element with id="app_type" (and given that the change handler uses that ID it was a reasonable assumption that it was meant to go on the `select` element)

Comment: ...about which, @user2361273,  a div is never going to trigger the `change` handler.   You probably want to move that ID to the `<select>` element.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - thats correct, but still no luck. Code is executing fine when div has radio input type instead of textarea. Is it because textarea is loading in DOM after JS is executed? Can this be solved by adjusting the placement of JS code in HTML file?

Comment: "Is it because textarea is loading in DOM after JS is executed?"  That would have been a good thing to mention in the question.  You are correct that you can't show an element that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems:

- Missing jQuery in the snippet
- Missing `#app_type` as an id on the select element
- Improper JavaScript syntax

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#app_type").on("change", function() {
        var selectedTestType = $(this).find("option").filter(":selected").text();
        $(".hideable").hide();
        if (selectedTestType == "App-1") {
          $("#show_element").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#show_element {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Form Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form role="form" method="post" action="form_verify.php">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group" id="form_id">
                <label>Form Element</label></br>
                <select id="app_type" class="form-control" name="form_element">
         <option selected disabled>-- Select Application Type --</option>
         <option>App-1</option>
         <option>App-2</option>
        </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group hideable" id="show_element">
                <label>Steps</label></br>
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Steps" name="form_steps" type="text" value="" rows="2"></textarea>
              </div>
```